# why can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python

I have this code that runs without error:

```
result={}
for i in range(1):
    a="Bug: from the English bug — bug, bug, bug in the program".split()
    result[a[0][0:-1]]=result.get(a[0][0:-1],[]) + [' '.join(a[1:])]  # ' '.join(a[1:]) - error
print(result)
```

However, I do not want to add a one-element list to the `.get` result, but a string, like so:

```
result={}
for i in range(1):
    a="Bug: from the English bug — bug, bug, bug in the program".split()
    result[a[0][0:-1]]=result.get(a[0][0:-1],[]) + ' '.join(a[1:])
print(result)
```

But this causes an error that says `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`. Why?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. Are you getting an error? Alternatively, are you asking why `result.get(a[0][0:-1],[]) + ' '.join(a[1:])` that is `list + string` does not work?

Comment: What's the expected result of such concatenation?

Comment: The initial value for your dict elements (set via the second parameter to `.get()`) is an empty list.  Once you have a list, the only thing you can add to it is more lists.  If you had initialized it to an empty string instead, then you could add strings to it.

Comment: It's more convenient for the `+` operator (when the left hand side is a list) to *concatenate two lists* rather than *append a scalar to a list*. For example, if Python were changed so that `[0] + 1 == [0, 1]` then what should `[0] + [1]` be? And `[0] + [1,2]`?

Comment: @JonSG The code that gets the error is when he changes `[' '.join(a[1:])]` to just `' '.join(a[1:])`

Comment: I think you can do what you want more clearly using the `insert()` method.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity, but I think it should be closed as a typo. Of course `result.get(a[0][0:-1],[])` will return a list (an empty list) in the case that `a[0][0:-1]` is not found - **that's the purpose** of the `,[]` part. So the rest is simply about reasoning about the code: when we get an empty list, we can't add a string to that; and we will get the empty list, because the dict starts out empty. If there is something specific you could not figure out by yourself, I don't know which part it is.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I understand everything, thank you for your help :)

Comment: This would be much easier to and and understand with some temporary variables. For example, `a = "..."; key, value = a.split(None, 1); key = key.strip(':'); result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your `get(a[0][0:-1], [])`, the `a[0][0:-1]` or `Bug` key does not exist, so instead it instantiates the 'Bug' key in the dictionary and sets its value to the empty list `[]`. At that point, an addition operator is treated as a concatenation and you can only concatenate lists to lists.

You can alternatively use a default value of an empty string `''` instead in your `get` and then you can use `' '.join(a[1:])`.

```
result = {}
for i in range(1):
    a = "Bug: from the English bug — bug, bug, bug in the program".split()
    result[a[0][0:-1]] = result.get(a[0][0:-1], '') + ' '.join(a[1:])
print(result)
```

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be a list and they want to insert a new element before the last element of the list.